# Is it normal that when in Ubuntu I can see all of my Windows files? Are my files created in Ubuntu private?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, privacy, privileges

please forgive my lack of knowledge but I am slightly confused, I recently installed Ubuntu as lately I have favoured using certain Linux distros much more than using Windows 10, sadly I have found I have had to keep Windows due to certain softwares I need to use on rare occasion and so decided to dual boot my pc

I created a free space partition in Windows and when installing Ubuntu chose to install alongside Windows this told me it was creating two other small partitions and then the installer did its thing and I am assuming used the free space for the Ubuntu install.

My question is, is it normal that when in Ubuntu I can see all of my Windows files ? Secondly are my files created in Ubuntu private ? I don't mind being able to see my Windows files in Ubuntu but I would prefer that my Ubuntu ones are not viewable when using Windows, might seem silly to ask this but the free space partition I created seems to be being used but I can't help but wonder if the two os's are using one partition or two separate ones

Apologys if I've confused anyone this is the best I can ask this.

Comment: To better answer your question, can you copy the output of `df -h` and update your question to include this? Plus also a rough estimate to your knowledge how big is your Windows partition, how big is your Ubuntu partition. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows partitions can be made invisible by using umask 0777 in the fstab file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is normal that you can see your Windows files in Ubuntu, and no, you cannot see your Ubuntu files in Windows.  Windows does not understand the default filesystem Ubuntu uses, although Ubuntu understands the filesystem Windows uses.

Comment: Also, anyone with direct access to the hardware can see any of the files, regardless of what permissions you use on them in the respective systems. Files can be encrypted to prevent immediate access, though.